# rabbitmq prefetch with multiple consumers

Tags: rabbitmq

I'm trying to understand how rabbitmq works with multiple consumer and `prefetch_count`.

I have three consumers consuming on the same queue and all of these consumers have configured with the QoS `prefetch_count = 200`.

Now assuming at a certain point I have unlimited backlog messages in the queue and consumers `A,B,C` are connecting to the queue, would A get message 1-200, B get 201-400, C get 401-600 from the queue simultaneously? That seems like message `1`, `201`, `401` got processed at the first place compared to the rest. Somehow I don't want that, I'd like to have these messages being processed sequentially.

If that's the case I guess this implies that the messages may be processed disordered based on how consumers are setup, even though the queue follows FIFO.

Or should I set prefetch_count = 1 to make sure of REAL FIFO?

**Edited:**

Just set up a local env of rabbitmq and experimented a bit. I used a producer to bombard a queue with numbers 0 to 100000 sequentially to accumulate backlog messages in a queue. Later on, I had two consumers A, B consuming messages from that queue with prefetch_count = 200.

From what I observed, A got 0-199 and B got numbers 200-399 at very beginning. However, A started getting numbers {401, 403, 405, 406 ...} and B gets {400, 402, 404, ...} after that.

I guess A and B got non-skipped messages at the beginning was because I wasn't strictly spinning up these two consumers simultaneously. But the following pattern explains well how `prefetch_count` works. It doesn't necessarily send consumers consecutive messages(I knew it's processed in a round robin fashion, but I guess this is more intuitive with an experiment). There's no guarantee in what order the messages will be processed if using `prefetch_count`.